# Reviewing - double click

Tags: bug, review-queues, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I think there's a problem with reviewing some (or all) queues. Sometimes if I click for example "recommend deletion" on one question before reading content of the second one action for the second one is made the same as for the one I reviewed.

I've had this issue just a minute ago and I got again `You have made too many incorrect reviews` even if I wanted to review this post in different way (and now I need to wait 2 days again).

I use Firefox. It's hard to say how it's happening because it's happening not too often however it happens from time to time for sure.